# Matlab 3D Vector

Tags: matlab, 3d, cad

I have two 3D vectors in 3D line plot in Matlab. How I can specify an angle name between them? And also an angle between any two crossing lines?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by an "angle name"? If you wanna save the angle value under a variable: mathematically, it will be a map/function. you can save the values onto an array indexed by the vectors or lines you have for efficient recalling.

If you are asking for a method to obtain this angle, i.e. the function mentioned above, you can use dot product to do it.